# Is it possible to shortcut/bypass other IErrorHandlers in WCF?

Tags: wcf, ierrorhandler

I am developing a rather large application and would like to implement IErrorHandler multiple ways for different conditions.  However, it appears that ALL of the instances will be called for every error.  Is there a way I can tell WCF that the error has been handled by a particular instance so that any handlers remaining in the list are not called?

(For a little more detail, we are using a 3rd party toolkit that adds a "default" error handler.  This means that no matter what we do, this handler will be invoked and reverses some of our changes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a provider pattern and inside it have a list of your error handlers. You could then have whatever condition you like to delegate to the handler of your choice.

Ie you would hook up 1 error handler that contains all your handlers instead of hooking up many which all get executed sequentially.

Comment: Yes, that would work in the majority of cases; however, the Web API adds a default error handler directly to WCF so this wouldn't solve the problem of bypassing that error handler.  Fortunately, since my original post last year, Microsoft has updated the Web API code so the default handler is not called when a custom handler has 'handled' the error.  Good suggestion, though.